# Telerik RadChart Not showing when there is 2 charts

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, telerik, telerik-charting

Is it possible to have multiple charts on one page? When I try both charts don't want to display. There maybe something I am missing on the layout? The charts work find individually if they are the only chart on the page.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted some of the relevant code/xaml we could help you debug it

Comment: The code is using their example from 

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/chart/series/pie/pie-series

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/chart/series/cartesian/bar-series

and working on separate pages there is no issue. 

The layout used is a a simple Grid with 2 row definitions. Putting a chart in row=0 and a chart is row=1